# Take out single record of each type on basis from arraylist

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

I have a ArrayList of String array. String array looks something like below

```
["Type-A","Date","Expert"]
["Type-A","Date","07 Expert"]
["Type-A","Date","10 Expert"]
["Type-B","Date","Expert"]
["Type-B","Date","10 Expert"]
["Type-C","Date","07 Expert"]
["Type-C","Date","10 Expert"]
```

Consider arraylist have above string arrays. I want to take out unique type from each type from arraylist on thee basis of expertise level. If we cosider above list then I want Type-A with level as Expert and Type-B with level as Expert and Type-C with level as Expert10 as in hierarchy Expert is at top and Expert10 and Expert07 are lower to it.

The structure is like I have arraylist which contains string array. Each String array record has **Type** and **expertise level**. Arraylist can have multiple records of same Type with different expertise level. I want record of each Type but with highest expertise level. I have a list if different expertise level. Now my confusion is how to use that expertise level list to take out or make another arraylist with single record of each type with highest expertise level.

List of expertise level.

```
Expert 
10 Expert  
07 Expert
Professional
Systems 
10 System 
07 System
```

Comment: Is array list is sorted by `Type`??

Comment: @Srinivasu: No, arraylist is not sorted.

Comment: Is it available to change the representation of the data, I mean using map of string (Type) and List of objects (corresponfing to the array) instead of ArrayList of arrays ?

Comment: WOW! You changed the question. @SandeepKumar. Isn't stackoverflow a very good `code for me` site?

Comment: @afzalex: Appologies. I just added the different expertise level. I am not expecting the actual code but just the direction or simple algorithm.

Comment: Just create a list of expert levels in increasing order of hierarchy. Then compare expert level of given type in that list (The position in that list). And if the position is greater than already present expert than replace it.

Answer (score 0):

Just loop it and find out, using a map to store current max expert item for each type during looping:

```
private boolean isMoreExpert(String expertPicked, String expertToCompare){
    //TODO: return true is expertPicked is lower expert than expertToCompare, false otherwise
    return false;
}

private List<String[]> mapToList<Map<String[]> map>{
    //TODO: iterate the map and store items to a list
    return null;
}
private List<String[]> getMostExpertListOfEachType(List<String[]> items){
    Map<String, String[]> tempRecord = new HashMap<>();
    for(String[] item in items){
        //assume first item is the type
        String[] current = tempRecord.get(item[0]);
        //assume the third item is the expert 
        if(current != null ){
             if(isMoreExpert(current[2], item[2])){tempRecord.put(item[0], item);}
        }else{
            tempRecord.put(item[0], item);
        }
    }
    return mapToList(tempRecord);
}
```

Have not tested the code yet:)

Answer (score 0):

Here I used `Pattern-Matcher` to extract expert level. Iterate the given array and then created array, If Same type is found - compare expert level - if expert level if created is smaller - then replace with iterated expert.

```
List<String[]> givenExp = Arrays.asList(
        new String[]{"Type-A", "Date", "Expert"},
        new String[]{"Type-A", "Date", "Expert07"},
        new String[]{"Type-A", "Date", "Expert10"},
        new String[]{"Type-B", "Date", "Expert"},
        new String[]{"Type-B", "Date", "Expert10"},
        new String[]{"Type-C", "Date", "Expert07"},
        new String[]{"Type-C", "Date", "Expert10"});
List<String[]> filteredExp = new ArrayList<>();
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(?<=Expert)\\d*"); 
Matcher gmat, fmat;
String gexplvl, fexplvl;
int giexplvl, fiexplvl;
main:
for (String[] gexp : givenExp) {
    for (String[] fexp : filteredExp) {
        if (fexp[0].equals(gexp[0])) {
            gmat = pat.matcher(gexp[2]);
            fmat = pat.matcher(fexp[2]);
            gmat.find();
            fmat.find();
            gexplvl = gmat.group();
            fexplvl = fmat.group();
            if (gexplvl.length() == 0) {
                filteredExp.remove(fexp);
                filteredExp.add(gexp);
            } else {
                if (fexplvl.length() != 0 && Integer.parseInt(fexplvl) < Integer.parseInt(gexplvl)) {
                    filteredExp.remove(fexp);
                    filteredExp.add(gexp);
                }
            }
            continue main;
        }
    }
    filteredExp.add(gexp);
}
for (String[] fexp : filteredExp) {
    for (String val : fexp) {
        System.out.printf("%-10s", val);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

**Output :**

```
Type-A    Date      Expert    
Type-B    Date      Expert    
Type-C    Date      Expert10
```

Comment: your code would work for record having expert word in expertise level. I have edited my question with actual values for expertise levels..

Answer (score 0):

With Java 8 [Streams](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html), it is as simple as:

```
list.stream().sorted((s1, s2) -> s2[2].compareTo(s1[2])).filter(isMaxExpert())
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

private static Predicate<String[]> isMaxExpert() {
   final Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<>();
        return p -> {
            if (map.get(p[0]) != null) {
                return false;
            } else {
                map.put(p[0], p);
                return true;
            }
     };
};
```

Usage:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.function.Predicate;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class SelectOne {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        List<String[]> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new String[] { "Type-A", "Date", "Expert" });
        list.add(new String[] { "Type-A", "Date", "07 Expert" });
        list.add(new String[] { "Type-A", "Date", "10 Expert" });
        list.add(new String[] { "Type-B", "Date", "Expert" });
        list.add(new String[] { "Type-B", "Date", "10 Expert" });
        list.add(new String[] { "Type-C", "Date", "07 Expert" });
        list.add(new String[] { "Type-C", "Date", "10 Expert" });

        List<String[]> modified = list.stream()
                .sorted((s1, s2) -> s2[2].compareTo(s1[2])).filter(isMaxExpert())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        for (String[] strArray : modified) {
            System.out.println(" " + strArray[0] + " " + strArray[1] + " "
                    + strArray[2]);
        }
    }

    private static Predicate<String[]> isMaxExpert() {
        final Map<String, String[]> map = new HashMap<>();
        return p -> {
            if (map.get(p[0]) != null) {
                return false;
            } else {
                map.put(p[0], p);
                return true;
            }
        };
    };
}
```